# How to maintain permissions when downloading in Fabric

Tags: python, sftp, fabric

If I have code like:

```
import fabric.operations
from fabric.api import settings    

def begin():
    with settings(host_string='blar', user='blar', password='blar'):
           fabric.operations.get('/remote/file', '/local/file')
```

How do I maintain the permissions during the file transfer if some files are executable and some aren't?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't. Your local file will be created owned by the user who initiated the fabric script and adhering to its umask. You can, however, change it in the next python call :)

Comment: That's the kind of definitive answer I like. Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

It appears [there's currently no way](http://fabric.readthedocs.org/en/1.4.3/api/core/operations.html#fabric.operations.get) as far as the API goes. Strangely, [there's not even a feature request for this](https://github.com/fabric/fabric/issues).

Comment: Thanks for the info. It's weird that you have the option with .put() but not with .get(). Thanks!

Comment: I'm sure that's because `put` is a lot more popular call than `get`, due to fabric being primarily a deployment tool.

Comment: Packing everything up into a `.tar.gz` file kept the permissions. Saved me some hassle and little bandwidth. I should've imagined, but I don't use Fabric as often as I should.